# Disable CRL check for VB6 applications

Tags: vb6, certificate, signing, certificate-revocation

One of our customers has an issue with our applications - they take about 2 minutes to start. I ran Process Monitor along with one of the simplest applications and found out the process is trying to connect to verisign.com. The computer running the app is not connected to the internet. The app is signed, so I figured I need to disable the certificate checks. For .net applications, it helped to add the generatePublisherEvidence configuration tag with enabled="false" attribute. However, there are some VB6 applications that cannot be configured this way.
I have checked the "Use Certificate Rules on Windows Executables for Software Restriction Policies" setting in Local Security Policy, it is disabled. The machine is not in domain. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to disable the check by modifying the setting in MSIE - Internet Options -> Advanced -> Security -> Check for publisher’s certificate revocation. It is important to uncheck the "publisher", not the "server" :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing some of the flags of [WintrustSetRegPolicyFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388201%28VS.85%29.aspx) for the logged on user?